# Azure SQL DW table not using all the distributions on the compute nodes to store data

Tags: azure-synapse

One of the Fact tables in our Azure SQL DW (stores the train telemetry data) is created as a HASH distributed table (HASH key is `VehicleDimId` – integer field referencing the Vehicle Dimension table). The total number of records in the table are approx. 1.3 billion.

There are 60 unique `VehicleDimId` (i.e. we have data for 60 unique vehicles) values in the table which means that they have 60 unique hash keys as well. Based on my understanding, I expect the records corresponding to these 60 unique hash key `VehicleDimId` should be distributed across 60 distributions available (1 hash key for 1 distribution).

However, currently all the data is distributed across just 36 distributions leaving other 24 distributions with no records. In effect, that is just 60% usage of the compute nodes available. Changing the Data Warehouse scale does not have any effect as the number of distributions remain the same to 60. We are currently running our SQL DW at DW400 level. Below is the compute node level record counts of the table.

[image]

You can see that the data is not evenly distributed across compute nodes (which is due to the data not being distributed evenly across the underlying distributions).

I am struggling to understand what I need to do to get the SQL DW to use all the distributions rather than just 60% of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash distribution takes a hash of the binary representation of your distribution key then deterministically sends the row to the assigned distribution. Basically an int value of 999 ends up on the same distribution on every Azure SQL DW predictably. It doesn't look at your specific 60 unique vehicle IDs and evenly divide them.

The best practice is to choose a field (best if it is used in joins or group bys or distinct counts) which has at least 600 (10x the number of distributions) fairly evenly used values. Are there other fields that meet that criteria?

To quote from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute?) adding some emphasis:

> Has **many** unique values. The column can have some duplicate values.
> However, all rows with the same value are assigned to the same
> distribution. Since there are 60 distributions, the column should have
> at least 60 unique values. Usually the number of unique values is **much**
> **greater**.

If you only have 60 distinct values your likelihood of ending up with even distribution is very small. With 10x more distinct values your likelihood of achieving even distribution is much higher.

The fallback is to use round robin distribution. Only do this if there are no other good distribution keys which produce even distribution and which are used in queries. Round robin should achieve optimal loading performance but query performance will suffer because the first step of every query will be a shuffle.

In my opinion, concatenating two columns together (as Ellis' answer suggests) to use as the distribution key is usually a worse option than round robin distribution unless you actually use the concatenated column in group bys or joins or distinct counts.

It is possible that keeping the current Vehicle ID distribution is the best choice for query performance since it will eliminate a shuffle step in many queries that join or group on Vehicle ID. However the load performance may be much worse because of the heavy skew (uneven distribution).

Comment: Thanks @GregGalloway. I am not sure I follow the first paragraph. I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute) article and it says we need atleast 60 unique values on the hash key column. Still struggling to understand why it would not distribute these among 60 distributions.
There are no other fields which satisfy the other conditions in the mentioned article. 
I have tried the round robin distribution but it was just non-performant in comparison to the hash distributed table.

Comment: @AKS as far as round robin being less performance are you talking about loading or query performance? I would guess it loaded pretty fast but was slower to query.

Comment: you are right with the round robin distribution. Loading data is fast but query performance is slow. I think I am going to leave the current hash distribution key even though it results in a bit of data skew. The query performance is the best with this distribution which is of paramount importance to us at the moment. We are okay with a bit longer ETL window. I am going to mark this as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a concatenated join key which could be a concatenation of two different keys which will create a higher cardinality than what you have now with 60 x new row cardinality should generally be in the thousands or greater. The caveat here is that key needs to then be referenced in every join so that the work is done one each node. Then, when you hash on this key, you'll get a  more even spread.

The only downside is that you have to propagate this concatenated key to the dimension table as well and ensure that your join conditions include this concatenated key until the last query. As an example, you keep the surrogate key in the subqueries and remove it only in the top level query to force collocated joins.

Comment: I have actually tried the key concatenation workaround and even though it distributes data evenly, the performance is worse off. So just to make it clear, concatenating keys - does it mean converting the individual integer keys to strings and concatenating them and storing it as a column on which to hash the distribution. And then while joining to dimensions extract individual keys from the string, convert them to integer. Is that what you mean or am I understanding it incorrectly? This really sounds like a cumbersome approach.

Comment: Can you tell us the other columns in the table? 60 values is a poor choice of distribution key, let's see if we can find something better.